# Add See All link to toggle and keep one open by default using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have several different toggles happening on an alphabet. I want to include a "See All" button which will open ones that are closed. Also, I want there to be one toggle (`div1` aka the letter A) that is automatically open with you visit the page.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var divname= this.name;
        $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    });
});
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="#" name="div1">A</a> B C D E F G H
    <a href="#" name="div2">I</a>
    <a href="#" name="div3">J</a> K L
    <a href="#" name="div4">M</a> N O P Q R
    <a href="#" name="div5">S</a> T U V W X Y Z See All
</p>
<div>
    <div id="div1" style="display: none;">testing div1</div>
    <div id="div2" style="display: none;">testing div2</div>
    <div id="div3" style="display: none;">testing div3</div>
    <div id="div4" style="display: none;">testing div4</div>
    <div id="div5" style="display: none;">testing div5</div>
</div>
```

Here's also the link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fL98p183/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Demo on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/fL98p183/2/embedded/result/)

HTML:

```
<p>
  <a href="#" name="div1">A</a>
  B C D E F G H
  <a href="#" name="div2">I</a>
  <a href="#" name="div3">J</a>
  K L
  <a href="#" name="div4">M</a>
  N O P Q R
  <a href="#" name="div5">S</a>
  T U V W X Y Z See All
</p>

<div>
  <div id="div1" style="display: none;">testing div 1</div>
  <div id="div2" style="display: none;">testing div2</div>
  <div id="div3" style="display: none;">testing div3</div>
  <div id="div4" style="display: none;">testing div4</div>
  <div id="div5" style="display: none;">testing div5</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#div1").show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");

    $('a').click(function () {
        var divname = this.name;
        $("#" + divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    });

    $('#seeAll').click(function() {
        $('#div1').show("slow")
        $('#div2').show("slow")
        $('#div3').show("slow")
        $('#div4').show("slow")
        $('#div5').show("slow")
    })
});
```